# How to switch off chapter and section numbering in the whole document?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters, koma-script

I want "Introduction" instead of "1. Introduction". The same with all sections and subsections. In the KoMa-classes if possible

I've googled like mad, but the only solution I found is usinge \chapter*{introduction} and then manually adding those chapters to the index-counter and the ToC.

I can't believe that there's no easy solution to this. Lots of people write informal books in latex which shouldn't look like scientific standard publications

Comment: `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the KOMA-Script manual, section 3.16, "Document Structure":

[image]

So to deactivate numbering of chapters, section, subsection etc. and only number parts, you can use

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\partnumdepth}
```

in the document preamble.

And if you do not want to number anything:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen}
```

Comment: @AlanMunn: In this case his second line of code serves.

Awesome Schweinebacke!

Comment: @TheoFreeman yes that's why I deleted my comment. I didn't actually need to know the answer but I thought you might.

Comment: I think that `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-9}` is more than enough… ;-)

Comment: @GuM Maybe, but KOMA-Script has a `\DeclareSectionCommand` that allows to set your own levels and `-\maxdimen` is the lowest available value. Maybe it would even be a good idea, if KOMA-Script would not allow to set a real level of `-\maxdimen`, because it uses this value internally also to locally deactivate numbering.